# Springboot application cannot find application.yml from external folder (@PropertySource)

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, yaml, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to write a **spring boot** app (for *tomcat*), which has an **application.yml** file for configuration.

My goal is to search for this yml file **FIRST from the resources**, and if it is not there, then **SECONDLY from the tomcat's conf folder**.

My code, which is not working:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.app")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound=true,value={"classpath:application.yml","file:${catalina.base}/conf/application.yml"})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
}
```

I want this, because if I work on my Eclipse, and want to **use Tomcat server from Eclipse**. In this case I want to use the resources folder. But if I build the war then I skip the yml file from it with the maven war plugin, and **deploy it manually to Tomcat**, I want to use the tomcat's folder.

- if I leave the yml file on the resources folder of the project, **it works**
- if I delete the yml file from the resources, and place to the ${catalina.base}/conf folder (which is the embedded tomcat for eclipse, I know it), **it doesn't work**
- if I delete the @PropertySource annotation, and leave the yml file in resources, **it works**

***So my app works only if the yml file on the resources folder, even if I add or remove the @PropertySource annotation.***

How should I set to search for the resources folder for first time, and if there is no yml file, then search for the second option, which is the tomcat folder?

Comment: Spring Boot by default looks for Properties files `application.properties`, `application.yml` and even for `@Profile` specific property files`application-prod.yml`, etc. in the **classpath**. So you don't need `@PropertySource` when your file is in classpath.

Comment: but if I set the PropertySource only for the remote file, it won't work also:
**@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound=true,value="file:${catalina.base}/conf/application.yml")**

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For files outside classpath you'd need `@PropertySource`.  Now the thing about Eclipse's Tomcat is that its tricky and the proprieties file stored there ends up in weird directory which is not *${catalina.base}/conf/a‌​pplication.yml* and that is why its not working. Try deploying your app in concrete Tomcat installation.